# Adding additional sns:Unsubscribe to SNS access policy results in InvalidParameter error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

This one's a head scratcher:

```
sns_policy = {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{ 
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : { "AWS": "*" },
        "Action" : ["sns:Publish", "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic", "sns:Unsubscribe"],
         "Resource" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:234234234:test",
         "Condition" : {
             "ArnEquals" : { 
                 "aws:SourceArn" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:234234234:function:*"
             }
         }
    }]
}

sns.set_topic_attributes(TopicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:234234234:test", 
    AttributeName = "Policy", 
    AttributeValue = json.dumps(sns_policy)
)
```

Adding the third `Action` array item, `sns:Unsubscribe` results in `Invalid parameter: Policy statement action out of service scope! (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter;` and removing `sns:Unsubscribe` works fine.

Why is this not being allowed by AWS? I need my lambda function to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe Queues to SNS::test topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Special Information for Amazon SNS Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_SpecialInfo.html) the `sns:Unsubscribe` is not listed as a valid SNS policy action.

Try using `client.unsubscribe(SubscriptionArn='string')` instead as per [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.unsubscribe).

Comment: I get ` invalidparameter: SubscriptionId is not valid.`

Comment: Are you passing the arn of the subscription (not the sqs)?

Comment: I was passing in the TopicArn not the SubscriptionArn